# How can I install Wi-Fi drivers from first boot on Raspberry Pi 3B?

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, wifi, pi-zero, headless

I'm trying to configure my `Raspberry Pi 3B` and `Raspberry Pi Zero` so that I can modify `cmdline.txt`, and have it install the drivers for my TP-Link adapter from first boot automatically. My Pi has faulty Bluetooth and WiFi, so I bought a `TL-WN725N V3` adapter (which shows the 8188eus chip from lsusb) in the hopes of having a headless setup without needing an Ethernet cord. I'm trying to modify `cmdline.txt` to run an **install.sh** file from the boot folder but I'm not sure where to start. I'm using the drivers from http://downloads.fars-robotics.net/wifi-drivers/8188eu-drivers/

Is it possible to do this whilst keeping the default init_resize.sh?

I'm using Raspbian Lite flashed with the Raspberry Pi Imager.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know why you are following this method

Easier way is installing drivers once on clean image and clone that image. So whenever you flash the cloned image to new sd card it will already have the driver

Comment: Thanks, this is the approach I'll go for. Do you know the easiest way to make an image from Windows but be able to use it on smaller SD cards? I've heard that Win32 Disk Imager has issues with this, but I can always just use Linux.

Comment: @cnnd There are many answers to this question. Please search them.